# Align images of different size in different div of the same row

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="row org-logo m-b-lg">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6  text-center">
        <a href="http://www.psychologicalscience.org/" target="_blank"><img src="/static/img/meeting-page/APS.jpg" alt="Logo for American Physiological Society (APS)" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <a href="http://www.bitss.org/" target="_blank"><img src="/static/img/meeting-page/BITSS.png" alt="Logo for Berkeley Initiative for Transparency in the Social Sciences (BITSS)" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <a href="http://www.nrao.edu/" target="_blank"><img src="/static/img/meeting-page/NRAO.jpg" alt="Logo for National Radio Astronomy Observatory (NRAO)" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <a href="http://www.spsp.org/" target="_blank"><img src="/static/img/meeting-page/SPSP.jpg" alt="Logo for Society for Personality and Social Psychology (SPSP)" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Above is the screenshot of a row of logos of different organizations. It is obvious that the logo of APS is not properly aligned with the other logo. What do I do if I want to align these logo images, each of different sizes, according to the center of the image?

Answer (score 2):

Just give this CSS and see if it looks okay?

```css
.img-responsive {
  min-height: 85px;
  max-height: 85px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Just a **note**, do not give both `width` and `height`.

Comment: It works somehow but it changes the size of the image. Is there anyway to not change the size of the image?

Comment: @adlius45 How do you want it? You said you need the images to be aligned right? If they are of different sizes, you will get it differently only...

Comment: Note: to avoid image rezising, just set "min-height" to the smallest height of your images and "max-height" to the largest height of your images.